# Full-screen between activities

Tags: android, fullscreen, android-fullscreen, android-immersive

I'm trying to use sticky immersive full-screen in my app (as described [here](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html)). However, when switching activities the navigation and status bar will show up at first and after a few moments disappear again.
Is there any way to ensure that my app stays full-screen across activities?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a full screen theme

in AndroidManifest

```
 <activity
android:name=".Launch"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
```

Comment: This only seems to remove the status bar (and not the navigation bar).

Answer (score 0):

**try thic code in your Activity OnCreate method**

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_hotel_image);
```

**i hope this work in your case**

Comment: This also removed only the status bar and not the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

try put your code under oncreate

it works for me